# Jquery get consistent width using document body

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

I want to get the width of a web page and discovered that using `$(window).width()` doesn't return a consistent value due to the width of the scrollbar which varies depending on the browser and whether or not the scrollbar is visible.

Instead of window I'm getting the width of the document body:

```
$('body').innerWidth()
```

It seems to return the correct value when testing. Has anyone had any issues using this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting body{width: 100%;} in css. You may need to place that code in a $(document).ready(function(){}); callback or in a short timeout. One problem with getting DOM elements sizes is that you can get the size before it's been calculated in its final state. Even though it looks the correct width instantly there may be a few milliseconds where it hasn't been calculated. Takes a little playing around with.

Hope that helps.